# Powershell ForEach loop works intermittently - works, fails, works, fails, works etc

Tags: powershell

I have this odd issue with some simple powershell code in Windows 10. I think it might be something i'm doing wrong but i'm not a powershell genius.

I have this:

```
$ix = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry('<some server with a range of multiple IP addresses here>).AddressList.IPAddressToString;
$e = If ($ix -ne $null) {$ix | % { $_.split('.')[0..1] -join '.'} | % {$_ + '.'}}                         ; 
$r = Get-NetRoute | ? AddressFamily -eq 'IPv4' | Select -exp 'DestinationPrefix'; ForEach ($e in $e) {$xline = $r -match $e}; write $xline
```

$ix is a range of IP addresses returned from a server into a list then worked on to get $e.

$e is a list of the first two octets of each IP address derived from a list of IP addresses.

$r is the routing table IPv4 addresses

The purpose is to match the first two octets of the IP addresses in $e with the first two octets of the IP addresses in $r and then return the matching $r route table IP address with $xline. This works as intended until it doesn't any more.

The issue is that it will work fine, then suddenly no longer work because $xline comes up empty even though the $ix, $e, and $r values are still populated and their related code is working fine. After several tries it will start working again for several more tries then stop working. I do not know what i'm doing wrong, or if this is even the right way to go about this but I like the relative simplicity of it. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `ForEach ($e in $e)` <-- that seems wrong to me.

Comment: what would you suggest in place of that?

Comment: Ya know I just played with it and it seems to work, its just a bit confusing to read. Usually you'd use a different variable (new) variable name. E.g `ForEach ($f in $e)`, then use `$f` inside the `ForEach`. That being said its probably not the cause of your bug.

Comment: Inside that `foreach` though `$xline` is being repeatedly set, so only the last iteration of the loop will represent its value. Are you sure thats what you intend? Tbh I don't really understand what your code is meant to do..

Comment: whats intended is to take the first two octets of each IP address in the list returned by the server (which I split out into $e). Then the list returned in $e is matched against the first two octets of each IP address returned from the routing table with "Get-NetRoute | ? AddressFamily -eq 'IPv4' | Select -exp 'DestinationPrefix'" - if an IP address in the routing table has those first two octets then its returned in $xline. basically its searching a list for the first two octets then returning the matching IP address from the route table. It does work for a while but will stop working.

Comment: Mine returns ipv6 addresses. Is this maybe why you're seeing errors?

Comment: hmmm, odd, the "? AddressFamily -eq 'IPv4'" should only return IPv4 addresses, does here. Maybe its grabbing an IPv6 and failing but I don't see that here. I tried it without the "? AddressFamily -eq 'IPv4'" and IPv6 addresses are also returned then but the issue still persists and when it does work like that it only returns the correct IPv4 address.

Comment: Its `$ix` that ends up containing ipv6 addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (I reformatted the code a little also to make it clearer to troubleshoot):

```
$ix = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($env:COMPUTERNAME).AddressList.IPAddressToString;

$e = If ($ix -ne $null) {
    $ix | ForEach-Object { ( $_.split('.')[0..1] -join '.') + '.' }
}   

$r = Get-NetRoute | Where-Object { $_.AddressFamily -eq 'IPv4' } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'DestinationPrefix'

$xline = ForEach ($f in $e) {
    $r -match $f
}

$xline
```

The major change is that `$line` is being set to all the values returned in the `ForEach` loop vs just the last one.

Also I took out an unnecessary `ForEach-Object`, as you could do what it was achieving in the earlier one.

Here's the fixes in your short format:

```
$ix = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry('<some server with a range of multiple IP addresses here>').AddressList.IPAddressToString;
$e = If ($ix -ne $null) {$ix | % { ($_.split('.')[0..1] -join '.') + '.'}                        ; 
$r = Get-NetRoute | ? AddressFamily -eq 'IPv4' | Select -exp 'DestinationPrefix'; $xline = ForEach ($e in $e) { $r -match $e}; write $xline
```

Answer (score 0):

To complement [Mark Wragg's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48947917/45375) with some **background information**:

- Since the `$r` in `$r -match $e` is an *array*, `-match` acts a *filter*: rather than returning a *Boolean*, as happens with a *scalar* LHS, matching elements in `$r` are *themselves* returned, as an *array*.

  - E.g., `@('aa', 'ab', 'bb') -match 'a'` yields `@('aa', 'ab')` (whereas `'aa' -match 'a'` - due to a *scalar* LHS - yields `$True` to indicate a successful match.
  - If no element of `$r` matches, you get an *empty* array (`@()`), which in many PowerShell contexts appears to be an "empty" result or "nothing".
- As Mark points out, in your `foreach ($v in $e) {$xline = $r -match $v}; write $xline` loop (I've replaced iteration variable `$e` with `$v` to avoid confusion), you assign to `$xline` *in each iteration* rather than *collecting all results*.

  - As a result, you only use whatever the *last* `-match` operation returned - which may or may not be the *empty array*, which would explain the intermittent "not working".
  - As Mark's code implies, you don't need an aux. variable inside the `foreach` loop at all, because the *entire loop* can be used as an *expression*, which means its *cumulative output* is output as-is (and can be captured in a variable, for instance).

    - Thus, `foreach ($v in $e) { $r -match $v }` is all you need.

---

Here's a streamlined solution that is less (explicitly) iterative (and presumably performs better, though that is unlikely to matter here):

```
# Get all IPv4 destination prefixes.
# Note the use of @(...) around the command, which ensures that its output
# is treated as an *array* (which it most likely is anyway, in this case).
$ip4routeDests = @(Get-NetRoute | 
                    Where-Object AddressFamily -eq IPv4 |
                      Select-Object -ExpandProperty DestinationPrefix)

# Get the first 2 octets of all IPv4 addresses followed by a `*` to form
# a wildcard expression used with `switch` below.
# IPv4 addresses are identified by the presence of a `.` in them (`-match '\.')
# Regex '^(.+?\..+?\.).*' matches the entire input while extracting only 
# the first 2 octets; e.g., '172.16.'
$ip4addrWildcards =
  [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($env:COMPUTERNAME).AddressList.IPAddressToString `
    -match '\.' -replace '^(.+?\..+?\.).*', '$1*'                                                            #`

# `switch` allows us to implicitly loop over all wildcard patterns and match
# the destination prefixes against each with `-like`.
# This directly outputs all matches, but note that they'll be in the order
# implied by $ip4addrWildcards, i.e., the order in which the wildcards are specified.
switch ($ip4addrWildcards) { default { $ip4routeDests -like $_ } }
```